# string index out of range python tuples

Tags: python, tuples

I have a nested tuple as such:

```
tuple = ((1, 2), 3)
```

I receive this tuple in another function and I want to be able to out put it as `3 1 2`

If I try:

```
for x in tuple[0]:
    print " %s %s %s" % (tuple[1], x[0], x[1])
```

I get this error `string index out of range`

If I try:

```
for x in tuple:
    print " %s %s %s" % (tuple[1], x[0])
```

I get as output `3 1`

Answer (score 0):

You should subscript correctly:

```
>>> t = ((1, 2), 3)
>>> t[1], t[0][0], t[0][1]
(3, 1, 2)
```

Comment: This was it. Didn't know I can use t[][] for nested tuples. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

This code will unpack any such tuple into a one-dimentional tuple(as long as the nesting stops at the level in the example):

```
new_tuple = []
for member in old_tuple:
    if type(member)==tuple:
        new_tuple+=member
    else:
        new_tuple.append(member)
```

Answer (score 0):

When you try:

```
for x in tuple[0]:
    print " %s %s %s" % (tuple[1], x[0], x[1])
```

Then when you are trying to print x[0], x[1], it shows an error because x is not a tuple.

It is just a variable which stores the value of tuple[0][0] in the first iteration and tuple[0][1] in the second iteration of for loop.

Answer (score 0):

#### First case

When you said `for x in t[0]`, you were accessing 1 in the first iteration and 2 in the second iteration, since t[0] = (1, 2). Thus, when you accessed x[0] and x[1] in the print statement you got an index out of bounds

#### Second case

You printed tuple[1] which is 3 and x[0] which is 1 in the first iteration. You should now be getting an error like not enough arguments passed.

#### Solution:

For this particular case:

```
print(t[1], t[0][0], t[0][1])
```

You could also run a for loop in the t[0]:

```
for i in t[0]:
    print " %s %s %s" % (t[1], i[0], i[1])
```

Finally, you could also convert the nested tuple into a flat one and then iterate with lesser confusion since you have one lesser dimension to worry about.